# How to call an action from another plugin after another action from a different plugin gets called

Tags: php, plugins, action, elgg

I have two plugins: **plugin_A** and **plugin_B**. In `plugin_A/actions/plugin_A/` there is an action **a_action.php**. In `plugin_B/actions/plugin_B/` there is an action **b_action.php**.

**plugin_A/start.php**

```
elgg_register_action("a_action", __DIR__ . "/actions/plugin_A/a_action.php");
```

**plugin_B/start.php**

```
elgg_register_action("b_action", __DIR__ . "/actions/plugin_B/b_action.php");
```

I would like **b_action** to be called after anytime **a_action** gets called.

How can I go about this.

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for that you simply call elgg function called action at the end of a_action.php

```
action('b_action');
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply @enRaiser. Can it be done from **plugin_B**, so that it is **plugin_B** that checks for the occurence of an ction?

Comment: in that case I suggest you unregister a_action.php in start.php of plugin b. and register b_action.php. and call action('a_action') at the beginning og b_action.php

Comment: Thank you @enRaiser

Answer (score 0):

I opted for plugin hooks:

```
elgg_register_plugin_hook_handler("action", "a_action", "pay_action_hook");

function pay_action_hook($hook, $entity_type, $returnvalue, $params) {
    if (/* My stuff works OK */) {
        return true;
    }

    register_error(elgg_echo('My stuff work out failed'));

    return false;
}
```